# Django-REST: Get User by username instead of primary-key

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am using the basic UserViewSet derived from ModelViewSet.
Retrieving a user with a primary-key via `api/users/<pk>` works fine.
But I also want to be able to retrieve a User by Username.

I have added a new detail route but I always get `404` on my server when I try to get the user with the url `/api/users/retrieve_by_username/altoyr`.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['get'])
    def retrieve_by_username(self, request, username=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(userName=username)
            return Response(user)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response("No user with username found!", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The Urls are registered via a router:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

# The API URLs are now determined automatically by the router.
# Additionally, we include the login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

I think I am missing an important part of building rest urls.

Comment: [Use filters](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)

Comment: Using a Queryparameter like http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters filters the list-results, but I want to  get one user or an error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by adding a list route like:

```
@list_route(methods=['get'], url_path='retrieve_by_username/(?P<username>\w+)')
def getByUsername(self, request, username ):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    return Response(UserSerializer(user).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and the url will be like:

```
/api/users/retrieve_by_username/altoyr
```

Comment: This looks good, after reading a bit about REST-Urls I think the Url should look like `/api/users/username/altoyr`. I will try your method when I am at home.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the retrieve() ViewSet action. You'll find more detail here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.response import Response

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = User.objects.filter(username=pk)
        contact = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=1)
        serializer = ContactSerializer(contact)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from [Anush Devendra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33723114/10316220) is right but need a little update due to deprecations on [v3.9](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.9-announcement/#action-decorator-replaces-list_route-and-detail_route).

> action decorator replaces `list_route` and `detail_route`
> Both `list_route` and `detail_route` are now deprecated in favour of the single action decorator. They will be removed entirely in 3.10.
> The action decorator takes a boolean detail argument.
>
> - Replace detail_route uses with @action(detail=True).
> - Replace list_route uses with @action(detail=False).

```py
...
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework import status

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False,
            url_path='username/(?P<username>\w+)')
    def getByUsername(self, request, username):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        data = UserSerializer(user, context={'request': request}).data
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I add `context={'request': request}` because I have `url` as HyperlinkedIdentityField in my serializer. If you don't have it, you probably don't need it.